# Image.xcassets: Can I specify different app icons for iOS 6 and 7?

Tags: xcode, ios6, ios7, icons, xcasset

I'd like to use different app icons on iOS 6 and 7. (I need this due to the different rounded rectangle shapes because my icon includes a border line.)

For most sizes this is not a problem because the sizes are different. However, the iOS 6 spotlight icon and the iOS 6-7 settings icon both use a 29*29 (non-retina) or 58*58 (retina) app icon.

I'm wondering if the new xcassets bundles could be used to specify different icon files for the different OS versions.

The `Contents.json` file inside the xcassets bundle specifies an array of images with various selectors such as `size`, `idiom` and `scale`. Unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation on the file format (probably it's not even public in Apple's view).

My question: Is there also a selector for the OS version that allows me to specify different 29*29 icons for iOS 6 and 7?

Answer (score -1):

With the introduction of the new `xcode` (`xcode 5`) you can now specify different app icons and launch icons in the assets file. Notice on the image below that in `xcode 5` you now have `image.xcassets` file. and in that file notice that you have `AppIcon` and `LaunchImage` and on that you have `iPhone Spotlight iOS 7 40pt` and `iPhone App iOS 5, 6 57pt`. `Jeremiah Smith` has indicated this isn't possible with an out of date link which was still valid until `xcodee 5` is released, but it is possible.

[image]

Comment: This is perfectly possible see my answer - this comment was due to Jeremiah Smith telling me I was completely wrong.

Comment: I'm of course aware of the xcassets editor in Xcode 5. My question was whether it's possible to specify different 29*29 icons for iOS 6 and 7.